# Problems calling Function with Argument (Need to pass File name from one function to another) Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to integrate 2 functions.

I have one sub function which works to loop through all files one by one.

once it has identified the file name.

It should call the function to run, on the opened file.

I can not seem to find a way to pass this on,

I did some reading on calling functions with arguments but when i try this i get a "compile error seperate list or )"

Can you please point me in the right direction?

I have posted the code below:

```html
Option Explicit
 Option Base 1

 Public Const DATASHEET As String = "MDFDATA"
 Public Const TABLECONVERSIONSHEET As String = "TABLECONVERSION"
 Public Const OPTIONSSHEET As String = "OPTIONS"
 Public Const FinalSheet As String = "Final Sheet"
 Public lByte_Order As Long 'byte order
 Public lData_Groups As Long 'number of data groups
 Public lChannel_Groups As Long 'number of channel groups
 Public lChannels As Long 'number of channels
 Public lTable_offset As Long 'row offset for the conversion table sheet
 Sub OpenFiles()
 Dim MyFolder As String
 Dim MyFile As String
 Dim sFile_Name As String 'MDF file name
 Dim lFile_Number As Long 'file number
 MyFolder = "C:\Users\Documents\Test"
 sFile_Name = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.dat")
 Do While sFile_Name <> ""
 lFile_Number = FreeFile
 Open sFile_Name For Binary Access Read Shared As lFile_Number
 Call PARSE_MDF


 Loop
 End Sub
 '==================================================================================================
 ' PARSE_MDF
 ' Main function
 ' Returns True if successful
 '==================================================================================================
 Function PARSE_MDF() As Boolean
 Dim sFile_Name As String 'MDF file name
 Dim lFile_Number As Long 'file number

 Dim lData_Groups_Counter As Long 'data groups counter
 Dim lChannel_Groups_Counter As Long 'channel groups counter
 Dim lChannels_Counter As Long 'channels counter
 Dim lRecords As Long 'number of records in data block
 Dim lRecord_Length As Long 'length of record in data block

 Dim lData_Group_Address As Long 'data group address
 Dim lData_Address As Long 'data address
 Dim lChannel_Group_Address As Long 'Channel group address
 Dim lChannel_Address As Long 'Channel address

 Dim byCol As Byte 'column counter for output
 Dim wsData_Sheet As Worksheet 'main worksheet
 Dim wsTable_Conversion_Sheet As Worksheet

 Dim rFirst_Signal As Range 'first signal in channel group
 Dim rLast_Signal As Range 'last signal in channel group
 Dim rSignals As Range 'range of signal names for a channel group
 Application.EnableEvents = False

 lTable_offset = 0
 Set wsTable_Conversion_Sheet = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets(TABLECONVERSIONSHEET)
 Set wsData_Sheet = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets(DATASHEET)


 'file selected
 If sFile_Name <> "False" Then
 'clear old data
 wsData_Sheet.Columns.Clear
 wsTable_Conversion_Sheet.Columns.ClearContents

 'set headers
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Signal name"
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Data type"
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Lsb"
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Offset"
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(5, 1).Value = "Bit length"
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(6, 1).Value = "Formula ID"
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(7, 1).Value = "Formula"
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(8, 1).Value = "First Bit position"
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(9, 1).Value = "Table length"
 wsData_Sheet.Cells(10, 1).Value = "Start Row"

 'offset columns because of headers
 byCol = 2

 'get file number
 lFile_Number = FreeFile

 'open file

 'check file integrity
 If IDBLOCK(lFile_Number) Then

 'check data exists
 If HDBLOCK(lFile_Number, lData_Group_Address) Then
 'main iteration for data groups
 For lData_Groups_Counter = 1 To lData_Groups

 'check channel group exists
 If DGBLOCK(lFile_Number, lData_Group_Address, lChannel_Group_Address, lData_Address) Then
 'channel group iteration
 For lChannel_Groups_Counter = 1 To lChannel_Groups

 'get channel group data
 Call CGBLOCK(lFile_Number, lChannel_Group_Address, lChannel_Address, lRecord_Length, lRecords)
 'set the first signal range in this channel group
 Set rFirst_Signal = wsData_Sheet.Cells(1, byCol)

 'channels iteration
 For lChannels_Counter = 1 To lChannels

 'get channel data for each channel
 Call CNBLOCK(lFile_Number, lChannel_Address, wsData_Sheet, byCol)

 'excel fudge
 If byCol <> 255 Then
 byCol = byCol + 1
 End If

 Next 'lChannels_Counter

 'set the last signal range in this channel group
 Set rLast_Signal = wsData_Sheet.Cells(1, byCol - 1)

 'format divider columns
 wsData_Sheet.Columns(byCol).ColumnWidth = 5
 wsData_Sheet.Columns(byCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
 wsData_Sheet.Columns(byCol).Interior.Pattern = xlLightUp
 wsData_Sheet.Columns(byCol).Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic

 'excel fudge
 If byCol <> 255 Then
 'for space between channels
 byCol = byCol + 1
 End If

 Next 'lChannel_Groups_Counter
 'get range of signals to get data for
 Set rSignals = wsData_Sheet.Range(rFirst_Signal, rLast_Signal)
 'get signal data

 'no channel data in this data group
 Else
 PARSE_MDF = False

 End If

 Next 'lData_Groups_Counter

 'no data in MDF file
 Else
 PARSE_MDF = False

 End If
 'not a MDF file
 Else
 PARSE_MDF = False

 End If

 'close file
 Close #lFile_Number

 'tidy up sheet
 wsData_Sheet.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
 wsData_Sheet.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
 wsData_Sheet.Rows("2:15").EntireRow.Delete
 wsData_Sheet.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
 wsData_Sheet.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

 'function ends normally
 PARSE_MDF = True

 'no file was selected
 Else
 PARSE_MDF = False

 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Function
```

Comment: The answer by @SickDimension is a good start.  The way to use arguments is that in the definition of the "FUNCTION", not sub, inside the () you set the variable types you expect to receive as arguments, and then AFTER the () you specify the type of output it returns.  Then somewhere in the function you define the value of it as a solution.  So, at the end, you would state, PARSE_MDF = True or False, if it's Boolean.  When it gets called, you can use it like a variable.  The whole function equates to a result that is able to be evaluated and compared.

Comment: Here is MSDN's page on passing arguments to procedures.  Check out the optional arguments section.  It's freeing.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the late response! Thank you for the information, much appreciated. I have it working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to pass the found filename as argument to the function. Now your function does not have an argument to pass it on so first of all create one such for ex.

```
Function PARSE_MDF(ByVal myFilePath as String) As Boolean
```

Then you need to change your loop to call the function correctly for ex.

```
 Do While sFile_Name <> ""
      ....
      myboolenvaluetohodthereturnvalue = PARSE_MDF(sFile_Name)
      .... 'does your funtion need to return value and be tested?

      sFile_Name = Dir() 'Call dir again without parameter to skip to next found file 
 Loop
```

Otherwise I haven't checked your code but this should get you started..

Comment: The key with this, that is missing from your explanation @SickDimension, is that "myFilePath" that you set As a String in the arguments can be used as that name as a variable.  You don't have to DIM it again, just start using myFilePath and whatever was passed through will be defined as that.  You can name it anything you want and inside the function it will conform to that name.

Comment: Good point @PJRosenburg, I always suppose some knowledge and problem solving skills but probably op hasn't that about this matter so that's a good addition.